# PHP jqGrid can edit the add/edit form properties?

Tags: php, jqgrid

When I add/edit the data, I would like the data being save into database (MySQL). Below is my jqgrid:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
          type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/custom.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js'></script>        
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myDataList").jqGrid({
        url: "<?= base_url(); ?>getmydata",
        datatype: "json",
        autowidth: true,
        mtype: "GET",
        colNames: ["Date", "Description", "Category", "Debit", "Credit", "Type", "Amount"],
        colModel: [{
            name: "transactiondate",
            editable: true,
            editrules: {
                date: true
            },
            formatter: 'date',

            formatoptions: {
                srcformat: "Y-m-d",
                newformt: "Y-m-d"
            },
            width: 1
        }, {
            name: "description",
            editable: true,
            width: 3
        }, {
            name: "category",
            editable: true,
            width: 1
        }, {
            name: "debit",
            sort: false,
            formatter: 'number',
            width: 1
        }, {
            name: "credit",
            sort: false,
            formatter: 'number',
            width: 1
        }, {
            name: "type",
            editable: true,
            hidden: true,
            editrules: {
                edithidden: true
            },

            formatter: function(cellvalue) {
                if (cellvalue == 'W') {
                    return 'Withdraw';
                } else if (cellvalue == 'D') {
                    return 'Deposit';
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },
            edittype: 'custom',
            editoptions: {
                custom_element: radioelem,
                custom_value: radiovalue
            }

        }, {
            name: "amount",
            editable: true,
            hidden: true,
            editrules: {
                edithidden: true
            }
        }],
        pager: "#myDataListPager",
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20],
        sortname: "transactiondate",
        sortorder: "desc",
        height: 'auto',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: "",
        editurl: "<?= base_url(); ?>getmydata/action",
    });
    jQuery("#myDataList").jqGrid('navGrid', '#myDataListPager', {
        add: true,
        edit: true,
        del: true,
        search: true
    }, { //prmEdit
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        afterSubmit: function() {}
    }, { //prmAdd
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        afterSubmit: function() {}
    });
});

<table id="myDataList"></table>
<div id="myDataListPager"></div>
```

My problem now is after edit or add, the form doesn't close. Also is that possible to readjust the add/edit form width and the input width for example, I want the description input as textarea instead of textfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I currently understand your first problem then you should add `recreateForm: true` option to both Add and Edit options. Default behavior of jqGrid is hiding of the Add/Edit form. At the next call the form will be shown again and some properties will be just tried to adjusted. So if the user first click Add button and then Edit then Add form will be created first and at the click on Edit button later jqGrid show Addit form back and just set some properties (title, call some callbacks and so on). More safe in my opinion to use `recreateForm: true` which first delete any old for if some exist and only then it creates new form.

The usage of `textarea` instead of `input` field can be managed by usage [edittype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#edittype) property: `edittype: "textarea"`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replied, I got this error msg Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined, after I clicked submit.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question:  In MySQL the date is stored in 2014-8-22 this format, and in my grid column this is what I set 

    formatter: 'date', 
    formatoptions:{srcformat:"Y-m-d",newformt:"Y-m-d"}

But when load the grid, the date display in 8/22/2014

I tried to change the srcformat to m/d/Y, mm/dd/yyyy, MM/dd/yyyy all return me a different date eg. 10/8/2188 1/1/1970... 
I want the date display in 2014-8-22, what format should I set?

Comment: You have to by careful in writing name of the properties. There are exist `newformat` and no `newformt` property. `srcformat: "Y-m-d"` is default value. So you could use `formatter: "date", formatoptions: {newformat: "Y-m-d" }`. The error `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` need be debugged. Which version of jqGrid you use? I recommend to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and **debug** your code (at least in Developer Tools of IE, press F12 to start and then start debugging of JavaScript code). You will see call stack during the error and all values of vars.

Comment: @user3687053: Is the problem solved, which you asked in the current question?

Comment: Thanks for the replied, nope yet, still trying to debug the property 0  error

Comment: Well in IE i can't even load the jqgrid this is the error message  Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid' point to this line " $("#myDataList").jqGrid({"

Comment: @user3687053: The problem can be because of **syntax error** in your JavaScript code. Some web browsers can fix silent some errors, but another web browsers (or versions of the same web browser) can stop with error. For example your code contains trailing comma which is an error (see `,}` in `editurl: "<?= base_url(); ?>getmydata/action",});`. Another example will be if you define object with *two* properties with the same name (something like `height: 250` and `height: "auto"`). Verify your current code for such error or just debug the code in the corresponding web browser.

Comment: @user3687053: I personally verify my JavaScript code in [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/). Both tools have many options which you can set as comments at the beginning of your program. In the way you can easy verify your code ignoring some not important warnings.

Comment: @user3687053: One more problem in your code is the usage of `jquery-ui-custom.min.js` and `jquery-ui.js` on one page. You should be very careful in inclusion of JavaScript libraries. You can't include the same library (especially in different version) more as one time.

Comment: Have remove one of the import ui.js and also using JSHint to verify the code, one warning is two undefined variables $ and jQuery

Comment: @user3687053: The warning is not important, but I recommend you to replace `jQuery("#myDataList").jqGrid('navGrid', ...);` to `$("#myDataList").jqGrid('navGrid', ...);`. **To fix your existing problem you have to debug your code in the corresponding web browser in which the error take place.** Your current code is still dirty. It have some HTML errors (try http://validator.w3.org/). For example  `<script>` have no `</script>`

Comment: Okay after I removed the afterSubmit: function() {}, it works well in both IE and Chrome. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @user3687053: You are welcome! By the way "empty" `afterSubmit` callback should return `[true,"",""]` or `[true]`.